# Delphi - Bridge two TCP ports

Tags: delphi, networking, portforwarding

Scenario:

PC1: (IP: 192.168.1.100)
Delphi application running 2 listenener at port 5555 and at port 80
Problem:
Application set up a both-way communication link beteeen port 80 and 5555.

PC2: (IP: 192.168.1.200)
Delphi application running a webservice listening at port 8888.
Problem:
Application makes a connection to PC1 at port 5555 and after that sets up a both-way communication link between local port 8888 and the connection to PC1.

PC2: Webservice 8888 (Listen) - Not a problem
PC2: Socket Connect to PC1 port 5555 - Not a problem
PC2: TCP Bridge between the Webservice and the Socket Connect (Problem)

PC1: TidServer 5555 (Listen) - Not a problem
PC1: TidServer 80 (Listen) - Not a problem
PC1: TCP Bridge between 5555 and 80 (Problem)

I have come this far:
PC2:
  WSocketLocal Connect local to 8888 (ok)
  WSocketExt Connect external to PC1 port 5555 (ok)

```
procedure TWebServForm.WSocketExtDataAvailable(Sender: TObject; ErrCode: Word);
begin
  WSocketLocal.SendStr(WSocketExt.ReceiveStr);
end;

procedure TWebServForm.WSocketLocalDataAvailable(Sender: TObject;
  ErrCode: Word);
begin
  WSocketExt.SendStr(WSocketLocal.ReceiveStr);
end;
```

---

PC1:
  IdTCPServer1 listen on 5555 (ok)
  IdTCPServer2 listen on 80 (ok)

The following two procedures works, So Scenario PC1 is done (working).

```
procedure TMain.ExtClientDataAvailable(Sender: TObject; Error: Word);
begin
   if Error <> 0 then exit;
   with Sender as TClient do
   begin
      Rcvd := Rcvd + ReceiveStr; 
      if (RemoteSocket.State = wsConnected) and (Rcvd <> '') then
      begin
         WSocketServerLocal.Client[0].SendStr(Rcvd);
         Rcvd := '';
      end;
   end;
end;

procedure TMain.LocalClientDataAvailable(Sender: TObject; Error: Word);
begin
   if Error <> 0 then exit;
   with Sender as TClient do
   begin
      Rcvd := Rcvd + ReceiveStr;
      if (RemoteSocket.State = wsConnected) and (Rcvd <> '') then
      begin
         WSocketServerExt.Client[0].SendStr(Rcvd);
         Rcvd := '';
      end;
   end;
end;
```

I want this result:
At PC1: In a webbrowser, http://127.0.0.1:80 shows the Webservice of PC2 port 8888

I know there are other and easyier ways to do this, but I have to be exactly as I have described.

How can I make the two "bridges" and what Delphi components should I use ?

Update: I have done the TCP Bridge with two Server Components, now I have to do the same operation with two Connect Components.

Update: I solved it, the two bridges is now working with the written code... But a new problem has appeared... When a webbrowser connects, it can make multiple connections at the same time to a port, my code only supports one connection at a time. I will investigate this.

Comment: looks like school homework...   http://torry.net/quicksearchd.php?String=proxy&page=2

Comment: No, it not school homework ;) I have seen on proxies, but is is not suatable in this situation. - The speciel about this is that the bridge at PC2 is an reverse connection and also a bridge.

Comment: that linked proxy for you is the source code you can learn from

Comment: I already have studied the YAP (Yet another proxy) Delphi source code. And it is not suitable for this at all. - And that is the reason thas I ask my question here at StackOverflow.

Comment: If there would be the ONLY client connecting at port PC1:80 then you can code it with any tcp library, no difference. If there can be several clients working simultaneously you would have to start with developing a protocol, that PC2-proxy would use to command PC2-proxy when to open new and close old connections, after you would make that protocol - it again would matter no more which TCP library to use to implement it.

Comment: And also there seems to hardly be a reason to code it in Delphi - just google for readymade "free tcp reflector" - the first one google gave me was http://blog.magiksys.net/software/tcp-proxy-reflector

Comment: I have tried already coding by using the TWSocket (ICS) and onData and onRetrieveData send/forward the data to and from the ports/clients/servers. - But I maybe be using the wrong components, and thats why I ask which Delphi components I should use.

Comment: The TCP Proxy Reflector is exactly what I am trying to make. But I need to  code it myself. 8-)

Comment: "I need to code it myself" - why? If not school - then why ? // No one knows, you did not show the code, you did not described exact problems you met. There is ICS, Synapse, Indy, there is Windows API - they all are suitable in their own way. If you want to code it - you need to find experts in your library and make them want to help you with your program. Personally I think your question would have more appeal if you would understand mood of people writing stuff like catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: I did describe the exact problem. How do I bridge two TCP ports in Delphi. - Nothing more, nothing less. - I also added that it had to be exactly like I have described, so why do you waste your time by filling in with stuff that don't reflect my question. - Fyi, the reason that I need to code it myself is that I need full control of it for later use. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You seem to not understand the basics of using sockets, with *any* socket library. Your issue boils down to two fundamentals: 1) "*how to read an arbitrary buffer of data from a socket*" and 2) "*how to write an arbitrary buffer of data to a socket*". If you knew how to do those two things, with *any* socket library, then writing a bridge between two sockets would be easy. Read a buffer on one socket, write it to another socket. The details are just semantics of the socket library you choose to use. So you need to stop what you are doing and go learn some basics first.

Comment: Well, I think I do understand the basic of using sockets. I can make a client/server taking to eachother. - but about this TCP bridging, I am/was unsure which components to use. Now I know, and offcouse I need to read/find out how to deal with that last issue. If you have any hints in written code I will appreciate it, otherwise I would thank you for you help and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "bridge" two ports together directly, where data just magically passes from one port to the other automatically.  You need proxy code sitting in between the client and server to handle that.

In your first scenario, your proxy on PC1 can create two listening sockets, one on port 5555 and one on port 80, and then any data received from a connected client socket on one port can be passed to a connected client socket on the other port.

In your second scenario, your proxy on PC1 can create a listening socket on port 80, and then create a separate outbound socket to 192.168.1.200 at port 5555, and then any data received on one socket can be passed to the other socket.

You haven't explained how you are actually implementing your socket/webserver communications in your Delphi apps.  If you are using [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org) components, for instance, then scenario 2 can be handled using Indy's `TIdMappedPortTCP` or `TIdHTTPProxyServer` component, which will do the bulk of the work for you.  But scenario 1, because it involves two listeners, you will have to manually link them together in your own code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. - Hang on, I have to edit this post.

Comment: I have come this far, Scenario1: <br/>Two TServerSockets (SS1, SS2) Both listening.<br/> onSS1ClientRead: SS2.Socket.Connections[0].SendText(SS1.Socket.ReceiveText); <br/>onSS2ClientRead: SS1.Socket.Connections[0].SendText(SS2.Socket.ReceiveText);<br/><br/> About the 2 scenario, I can see you misunderstand :)<br/> It is very important that THIS PC is making the connection to PC1 (not the other way around), So I am trying to do something similar as scenario 1 with one listener and one connector.<br/> But I can't figure the puzzle. Could I solve the scenario 1 with the TIDMappedPortTCP

Comment: That information should have been added to your question, not posted in a comment. In any case, for scenario 1, you have the right idea (though you should use `ReceiveBuf()` and `SendBuf()` instead). And no, you cannot use `TIdMappedPortTCP` for scenario 1, but you can use `TIdSimpleServer` or `TIdTCPServer` instead.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying about scenario 2.  Your question was very clear about it (webbrowser on PC1 connecting to webserver on PC2 via a local proxy), and I answered it accordingly, but now you are changing the details and making your real intentions less clear.  Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36647425/edit) and explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have updated the main question. Now I know that components to use, thank you. - I have not changed the main scenario. - Can you advise with from my updated question ?